# “I have been travelling” or “I had been...” or “I was...”?

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect, past-perfect

My teacher asked me where had I been because I was very late.

What would be the best answer?

1. I **have been** travelling from my hometown to here, so I have came late
2. I **had been** travelling from…
3. I **was** in travel / travelling from…

(Note: that morning I was in my hometown where is far away from my university .. so it took me 1.5hr to come to my class)

Comment: Did the teacher ask the question when you came late into the classroom or after class? In other words, did the teacher say: '_Where have you been? You are very late._ Or: '_Where were you? (or possibly, 'Where had you been?') You were very late._'

Comment: He asked me inside the class directly after I came in .. And he said " where have you been " ..

Comment: "I have been traveling" implies that you still are traveling or have just finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first and third excuses are reasonable, the second is not so good.

I would use "had" but in a different sense, to make it seem as though it was not your fault.

> I had to travel from my home town, and I caught the first bus out.

Comment: I understood what you mean .. thanks ! Or I can use **had** in case he asked " where had you been before come here " right?

Comment: If the teacher's question is ungrammatical, reply in the same style rather than correct him. Aside: if you are at university it is none of the teacher's business why you were late. A simple apology will usually do, perhaps with "due to events beyond my control".

Comment: I just want to know when I can say I had been travelling .